# Add bold formatting to localized string that has placeholders

Tags: xaml, mvvm, localization, windows-store-apps

I have a localization string with a placeholder:

```
Verb {0}
```

I use this string in my view-model to return a string to my view that, in turn, is displayed in a `TextBlock`.  Easy enough.  But a new requirement has arisen saying that the "Verb" portion (everything other than the placeholder's inserted value) be displayed in bold.

Using a string with placeholders seems like the typical and easiest way to indicate word order.  So the first question, then, is: where should I parse the localization string in order to add the bold formatting?  The parse operation will need knowledge of the original placeholder's location.  So far, the view-model has been responsible for utilizing the localization strings by using `string.Format` to insert values and return its result to the view.  If I leave this responsibility in the view-model, as is probably necessary, then the view-model also needs to return rich text.

Is binding to rich text even supported by `RichTextBlock`?  Even if it is supported, I've never before had a view-model return formatted text before.  It initially feels sacrilegious to a follower of MVVM-ism, but perhaps upon further consideration I may find it acceptable.

What's the best way to add bold formatting to a localized string that has placeholders?  Is returning rich text from the view-model the best way?

Comment: If you can translate the verb and placeholder separately (not generally possible to do automatically in every language, as the verb will often change forms based on the placeholder), then you can use the fact that `TextBlock` can have multiple `Run`s as children to your advantage. Try adding this as the `Content` (child) of your `TextBlock`: `<Run Text="{Binding Verb}" FontWeight="Bold"/>(\r\n)<Run Text="{Binding Placeholder}"/>`. Replace (\r\n) with a line return.

Comment: @NateDiamond - The verb and placeholder's content are translated separately without issue.  I don't have `Verb` and `Placeholder` properties.  Even if I somehow create them, hard coding their display order in XAML won't work since word order varies by language.

Comment: Are you able to process the text after retrieving it and tell which portion is the Verb and which is the Placeholder? If so, then what I would do is make a Model which stores the text and a `bool` for `IsVerb`, which your `ViewModel` will process and create. Then, use an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` which binds the `FontWeight` to `IsVerb` and passes it through a `Converter`.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd894487(v=vs.95).aspx).